# Why does my main content area not stop at the edge of the screen?

Tags: css, html

In my web site I am trying to lay out I am trying to get my page to have a left side sidebar/menu area with the main content area to the right.  I want my main content area to stop at the right edge of the screen, so I tried to give the area a `width: 100%`, but this doesn't seem to work right.  It seems to be 100% width, but then shifted to the right (and thus going off the side of the screen.

The code and result can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/KallDrexx/xmmSV/5/

How can I accomplish this to keep all the text in the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `main-area`, remove the `width:100%` and `position:absolute`, replace the `left:160px` with `margin-left:160px` and you're done.

Comment: That mostly worked.  The only issue is that in chrome it doesn't go to the end of the blue area like it does in IE, it's a good 150 or so pixels from the right.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's because `#main-area` is set to 100% width, which will be 100% of the container (which is this case is `body`. So, it will be 100% of the page width. But because you're moving it left 160px, it's actual position is 100% of the body + 160px.

Does the layout need to be fluid? If not, you can just set the width of #main-area in pixels.

Comment: if you reload the page I wrapped it all in a `page` div that's 100% width, and yet the `#main-area` (which is inside `#page`) is still past the screen

Comment: Alochci's got it - your `page` div is still 100% of the body width, so your absolutely positioned div will still be 100% of that div, which is 100% of its container (`body`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace the: `width: 100%` with `right: 0px` of `main-area`.

Basically this tells that the right side of the box should be 0px to the left of the parent.
Now the `main-area` is still able to scale with the page width.